# Testing Div Sizing Changes

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to find a workable way to set up some jest/enzyme tests for a size watcher component in a react project.

At present I'm watching the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` of a wrapper div to check for sizing changes from the parent. The div itself is styled to fill its parent box with no extraneous border/whitespace i.e., width: 100%, height 100%, margin/padding 0px... etc.

This brings me to my issue. what is a good way to create a mock/wrapper to test this with? I cannot directly alter `clientWidth` or `clientHeight` as they are protected, and since I'm using jest/enzyme, modifications to parent css styling do not really "flow" like they do in a browser. I don't really have access to anything like jquery to "cheat" so... any advice on how to create a test scenario for this?

Comment: Not completely sure what jest/enzyme is, but if you want to control the client size, have you considered sticking your page in iframes to see how they would react to smaller "windows"?  There's also the developer tools in some browsers that let you go into responsive mode to control the page size, which you may already be aware of, and you may be trying to automate this, which would probably be a no go.

Comment: Thats the thing, the jest/enzyme testing fameworks don't seem to really propagate the DOM changes like they would in a real browser. I kinda feel like I've hit a weird corner case of automated testing :|